# Matlab: data from cell matrix to struct. How can I to organize my data with keys?

Tags: matlab, data-structures, struct, dataset, organization

Let me suppose I'm facing some data obtained a by SQL database query as below (of course my real case is bigger, thoudans of rows and many columns).

```
key_names  header1  header2  header3
-------------------------------------
key1         a         1       bar
key2         b         2       foo
key3         c         3       bla
```

My goal is to organize data in Matlab (at work I must use it) in a smart and effecient way to get the following results:

- Access data by key obtaining the whole row, like `dataset(key, :)`
- Access data by key plus header getting back a single value `dataset.header(key)`
- If possible, getting a whole column (for all keys).

First of all, I used the `dataset` class provided by the *Statistic Toolbox* because it has all these features, but I decided to move away because it is really slow (from what I got, basically it is a wrapper onto cell arrays): the bottleneck of my code was getting the data instead of performing computations. In fact, I read that is better trying to avoid it as much as possible.

The newer class `table` looks more efficient but still not very much: from what I have understood, it is the new version of `dataset` as explained in the official [documentation](https://it.mathworks.com/help/stats/dataset.html?searchHighlight=dataset&s_tid=doc_srchtitle).

I considered also using `containers.Map` but it looks not to have the access by both key and column.

Therefore, `struct` seems to be the best choice as it is really fast and it has all the features I'm looking for.

So here my questions:

- Did someone face my same problem? Which way to organize data is the best one?
- Let me suppose `struct` is the best. How can I efficiently **create** and **fill** a structure like this: `mystruct.key.header`?

I'd like to get something like this:

```
 mystruct.key1.header1
 ans = a
```

Of course I could loop but there must be a better way. I documented [in this good starting point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5291331/dynamic-structure-generation-in-matlab) but the `struct` is created empty:

```
fn1 = {'a', 'b', 'c'}; %first level
fn2 = {'d', 'e', 'f'}; %second level
s2 = cell2struct(cell(size(fn2(:))),fn2(:));
s = cell2struct(repmat({s2},size(fn1(:))),fn1(:))
```

In the [`cell2struct`](https://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell2struct.html)  documentation all the examples do not rename all the levels. The [`deal`](https://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/deal.html) help is a good way to fill the data (depending on the Matlab version as from 7.0 it was substituted with a new coding style) but I'm still missing how to combine the parts of creating the structure with the filling one.

Any suggestion or code example is really appreciated.

Comment: Personally, I use `table` and find it both efficient and convenient to use. It seems to me like the perfect solution for your need. How do you import the data to Matlab? Do you use the **Database Explorer**?

Comment: I use the *Database Toolbox*, so basically I call `exec` and fetch the result. Importing and storing the data is not problematic, but accessing the stored data it is: profiling the code I found that the bottleneck is `dataset/subref` therefore I was thinking to switch to a faster "container" for my data.

Comment: What I'm saying is confirmed [here](https://books.google.it/books?id=9oqZBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA142&lpg=PA142&dq=matlab+tables+datasets+slow+performance&source=bl&ots=1wu_we2sA6&sig=-WALCodjHOH7smJeH5tBLwT0_iU&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjTxJbwqvfRAhVIXhoKHZfoA4gQ6AEIVjAH#v=onepage&q=matlab%20tables%20datasets%20slow%20performance&f=false). As a personal exercise, I'm trying without results to fill the `struct` but the only working solution I got is a poor nested loop. Even if you prefer `table`, do you have some hint to fill the data inside the nested `struct`?

Answer (score 0):

If you think, or sure, that structs are the best option for you, you can use [`table2struct`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/table2struct.html). First, import all the data into Matlab as a table, and then convert it to a structure.

```
mystruct = table2struct(data);
```

to access your data you would use the following syntax:

```
mystruct(key).header
```

if `key` is an array, then you need to collect all the values to a list using either a cell array:

```
values = {mystruct(key).header}
```

or different variables:

```
[v1, v2, v3] = mystruct(key).header
```

but the latter option is problematic if you are not sure hoe many outputs to expect.

I'm not sure what will be more convenient to you, but you can also convert to a scalar structure by setting `'ToScalar'` argument to `true`.